# Pattern Matching with Indexed Object

Tags: pattern-matching

If I have a list of rules associated with indexed variables like:

```
solution = {a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 10, a[3] -> 100}
```

I would like to be able to extract all of the values associated with the rules.  Although this problem is simple with a small number of variables, I am not sure how to generalize it.

For instance, I can use pattern matching to obtain 1 and 10, respectively:

```
a[1]/.solution
a[2]/.solution
```

However, I can't seem to generalize this to extract a[n] values from a list of rules.  What is proper pattern to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not what `Rules` are made for but the following  works well for simple cases:

```
solution[[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {1, 10, 100}
> ```

---

More "**proper**" way:

```
a /@ Range[3] /. solution
```

or equivalent suggested by Mr. Wizard

```
Array[a, 3] /. solution
```

---

For more nested list of rules you can use `Cases` (but then you have to keep an eye on what is what ;)) :

```
Cases[solution, (a[_] -> x_):> x, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {1, 10, 100}
> ```

Or the same but in different form:

```
Cases[solution, Rule[a[_], x_] :> x, Infinity]
Cases[solution, HoldPattern[a[_] -> x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

**Remarks** about `Cases`:

- For your example, default *levelspec* for `Cases`, which is `{1}`, will do the job.
- `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) will work with `solution` containing `Rule` (`->`) or `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) but for `Cases` we have to point this out:

---

```
solution = {a[1] -> 1, a[2] :> 5, a[3] -> 100}

Cases[solution, Rule[a[_], x_] :> x]
Cases[solution, (Rule | RuleDelayed)[a[_], x_] :> x]
```

> ```
> {a[1] -> 1, a[2] :> 5, a[3] -> 100}
> {1, 100}
> {1, 5, 100}
> ```

Comment: Great answer. I usually use e.g. `Array[a, 3]` myself, FWIW.  You might want to address the possibility of `:>` rules in your `Cases` methods.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. I saw this question and I've thought it is going to be closed, but I've failed looking for duplicate or extension example in documentation. (*I'm afraid to ask but what do you mean by your second remark?*)

Comment: What if e.g. `solution = {a[1] -> 1, a[2] :> $var, a[3] -> 100}` -- it would be good to at least mention that this won't be handled by the pattern `Rule[a[_], x_] :> x`.  By the way I notice you're using `HoldPattern`; if it is only for grouping you could use parentheses as well.

Comment: Why not just `solution /. (a[_] ->  x_) :>    x`   => {1, 10, 100}?

Comment: @TomD Good point, that's similar to `Cases` but simpler in form, you may add this example as an answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

Kuba already posted the natural ways to approach this problem, so here is an *unnatural* one.

You can temporarily (inside a `Block`) make the rules definitions for the Symbol `a` by setting `DownValues`:

```
rules =
 {a[1]->76,a[2]->36,a[3]->87,a[4]->42,a[5]->52,a[6]->73,a[7]->41,a[8]->58,a[9]->79};

Block[{a}, DownValues[a] = rules; Array[a, 5]]
```

> ```
> {76, 36, 87, 42, 52}
> ```