# Why is `Block` significantly faster than `ReplaceAll` for inputting variable values

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement

Given that the documentation for `FindMinimum` uses `ReplaceAll` for its various examples of what to do with the found solution to an optimization problem, it would seem to be the right tool for the job. However, the following MWE highlights the speed problem I ran into using `ReplaceAll` for such a situation. Is using `Block` the appropriate tool in this case and why?

```
vars = Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10000}];
vals = RandomReal[1, Length[vars]];
soln = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {vars, vals}];
Total[vars] /. soln // Timing
(*{1.395787, 4980.51}*)

Block[{f},
 ReleaseHold[
  MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2] &, Transpose[List @@ # & /@ soln]]]; 
  Total[vars]] // Timing
(*{0.033995, 4980.51}*)
```

A slight variation on the `Block` approach, which I expect would be equivalent, is also slightly slower (here both have been repeated 1000 times to show the less-significant difference of ~20%). Is there another approach that would achieve the same but faster?

```
Do[Block[{f}, 
   ReleaseHold[
    MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2] &, Transpose[List @@ # & /@ soln]]]; 
   Total[vars]], {1000}]; // Timing
(*{26.072036, Null}*)

Do[Block[{f}, (Set @@ # &) /@ (List @@ # & /@ soln); 
    Total[vars]], {1000}]; // Timing
(*{31.651188, Null}*)
```

Further testing has found that the problem is exasperated by "bigger" expressions than `Total`, in particular by the use of `ListInterpolation`. This appears to be resolved by only `Replacing` at the right level, which works in this particular example because all the variables have the same levelspec (`{-2}` or `{3}`).

```
vars = Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10000}];
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[vars]];
soln = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {vars, vals}];
i = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[1, 40], {-1, 1}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(0 &), "WarningMessage" -> False}];
expr = Plus @@ 
   MapThread[Times, RotateLeft[i@vars, #] & /@ Range[0, 4]];

expr /. Dispatch[soln] // Timing
(*{2.504619, 309.407}*)

Replace[expr, Dispatch[soln], {-2}] // Timing
(*{0.124981, 309.407}*)

Block[{f}, 
  ReleaseHold[
   MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2] &, Transpose[List @@ # & /@ soln]]]; 
  expr] // Timing
(*{0.146978, 309.407}*)
```

In the actually problem I am facing, not all the variables have the same levelspec, so it seems to require the range `{-2,-1}`, which ends up taking slightly longer than `Block`.

Comment: Try `soln = Dispatch[MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {vars, vals}]];`

Comment: As ilian says, `Dispatch[]` is quite invaluable if you have a lot of replacement rules.

Comment: @ilian This is a more than twice as fast on my laptop than the corresponding use of `Dispatch`: `(soln = AssociationThread[vars, vals];  Total[vars] /. soln) // AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Beat me to it.  However I believe you will find `Lookup` faster still in this case; reference: [(55980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Original question

As noted in the comments the use of [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) is the easiest way to make this replacement operation much faster.  However taking this as an opportunity to explore other optimizations here are some examples for you to consider:

```
(dsp = Dispatch[soln]) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0030
> ```

```
Total[vars] /. dsp // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0038, 5025.19}
> ```

It is faster if we focus the replacement on one level alone:

```
Replace[Total[vars], dsp, {-2}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0032, 5025.19}
> ```

Interestingly *levelspec* {1} appears slightly faster than {-2}:

```
Replace[Total[vars], dsp, {1}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0030, 5025.19}
> ```

Moving the `Total` outside prevents a wasted summation attempt:

```
Total @ Replace[vars, dsp, {1}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0019, 5025.19}
> ```

[`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) on an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) is faster however:

```
asc = Association[soln];

Total @ Lookup[asc, vars] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0017, 5025.19}
> ```

Finally, `Tr` is faster than `Total` on packed arrays, and packing has low overhead here:

```
Tr @ Developer`ToPackedArray @ Lookup[asc, vars] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00088, 5025.19}
> ```

### Updated question

In your update `expr` is a large expression containing many [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) subexpressions.  Each of these is significant:

```
expr[[1, 1]] // LeafCount    (* 153 *)
```

Further they each contain multiple packed arrays:

```
expr[[1, 1, 0]] /. x_List?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> Print[Short@x];
```

> ```
> {40}
>
> {4}
>
> {-1.,-0.948718,<<37>>,1.}
>
> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,<<23>>,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40}
>
> {0.947691,<<38>>,0.386701}
> ```

All of this is wasted space to search for a pattern match and every packed array must be first unpacked incurring additional overhead.  Since you only want to replace expressions in the form `f[_]` and since these all occur in the same place in each subexpression it will be far better to target the replacement accordingly.  That is exactly what you did with `Replace[expr, Dispatch[soln], {-2}]` which is faster than `Block` in this case.  (Indicientally `Block` avoids this problem because the evaluator will have flagged the `InterpolatingFunction` expressions as already evaluated and not depending on `f` and therefore not requiring updating, as part of its optimizations.)

Since the long `InterpolatingFunction` expressions appear as heads you could also use `Heads -> False` with almost the same efficiency even with Infinity as the depth:

```
Replace[expr, Dispatch[soln], {-2}] // Timing
Replace[expr, Dispatch[soln], ∞, Heads -> False] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.121, 319.564}
>
> {0.145, 319.564}
> ```

But at least for this example it brings up another question: why aren't you doing the replacement on `vars` first and *then* building `expr`?

```
With[{ivars = i @ Replace[vars, Dispatch[soln], {1}]},
  Times @@ NestList[RotateLeft, ivars, 4] // Total
] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.0237
> ```

---

By the way if all your replacements are of the form shown there is [a simpler way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31178/121) to use `Block`:

```
Block[{f},
  DownValues[f] = soln;
  expr
] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.143, 319.564}
> ```

Comment: `Dispatch` does improve the speed significantly, it wasn't as good as `Block` but once I had an `Evaluate` in the right spot it was just as fast (the evaluation order seems to be my biggest hurdle). 

I had forgotten about `Dispatch` as last time I used it, I didn't notice any improvement; something else must have been the bottleneck in that situation (or, I remember reading somewhere that in some situations it is used automatically?).

I can't test the `Lookup` method at the moment, but may be worth going through the effort of upgrading to v10 to get the further improvement.

Comment: Actually, for the case I am particularly interested in, `Dispatch` is still 20x slower than `Block`. I'll have to give it some more testing it appears...

Comment: @Joel I more representative example would be helpful in that case.

Comment: I have found that a more complicated expression causes trouble (although usually not more than 2 or 3 times). What really seems to aggravate it is when I put in a ListInterpolation; then `Block` is 10 or 20 times faster than `Dispatch` (depending on how big the expression is). Is that a small enough change to allow an edit/addition, or do I need to ask a new question?

Comment: @Joel Thanks for asking.  Mine is the only answer so I am the only one affected by a "moving goalposts" question, and I encourage you to make the edit.

Comment: Done. Using the right levelspec in Replaces does seem to do the trick, although in the actual problem I am facing, it still takes slightly more time.

Comment: @Joel I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. For the actually problem, the `Heads->False` and `{-2,-1}` methods are quite similar in time  (although still a bit slower than `Block`) and much faster than `ReplaceAll`/`Dispatch`. As for the last question, the building of the expression is a lot more involved than shown in the MWE, though it may be worth trying. Also `expr` gets passed to `FindMinimum` (to optimize over `vars`), so the work of building it has been done and I just want to evaluate it (e.g. at the solution, initial condition).