# Making ReplaceAll faster

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, parallelization

I have a list of functions `ncalc` that is calculated by

```
V[0][0] = {29.51, 26.98, 3.3256}; 
V[0][1] = {26.1194, 27.8766, 4.38633};
V[0][2] = {22.7297, 28.7663, 5.46013}; 
V[0][3] = {19.356, 29.6368, 6.59183};
V[0][4] = {16.0138, 30.4773, 7.82627};
V[0][5] = {12.7187, 31.2773, 9.20761}; 
V[0][6] = {9.48858, 32.0269, 10.7647};
V[0][7] = {6.34382, 32.7172, 12.5112};
V[0][8] = {3.30487, 33.3392, 14.46}; 
V[0][9] = {0.392168, 33.8839, 16.624};
V[1][0] = {30.3599, 30.4283, 3.35809}; 
V[1][1] = {26.9964, 31.2994, 4.52292};
V[1][2] = {23.6302, 32.1648, 5.69061}; 
V[1][3] = {20.3785, 32.9881, 6.86898};
V[1][4] = {16.9578, 33.8333, 8.21633};
V[1][5] = {13.6854, 34.614, 9.66453}; 
V[1][6] = {10.4785, 35.3459, 11.2789};
V[1][7] = {7.35433, 36.0215, 13.0703};
V[1][8] = {4.3304, 36.6335, 15.0487}; 
V[1][9] = {1.42411, 37.1742, 17.2242};
V[2][0] = {31.1995, 33.8811, 3.36074}; 
V[2][1] = {27.8651, 34.7249, 4.63509};
V[2][2] = {24.5225, 35.5668, 5.89674}; 
V[2][3] = {21.1919, 36.3939, 7.19607};
V[2][4] = {17.8938, 37.1933, 8.58349};
V[2][5] = {14.648, 37.9522, 10.1083}; 
V[2][6] = {11.4705, 38.662, 11.7962};
V[2][7] = {8.37303, 39.3187, 13.649};
V[2][8] = {5.36728, 39.9182, 15.6675}; 
V[2][9] = {2.46482, 40.4566, 17.8526};
umax = 9;
vmax = 2;
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], b] = 0.4;
layer = 5;
Do[Dizin[i + 1] = Array[V[i], umax + 1, 0], {i, 0, vmax}]
PTS = Array[Dizin, vmax + 1, 1];
hazır = BSplineFunction[PTS];
vektörler = hazır["Knots"];
dereceler = hazır["Degree"];
degree1 = dereceler[[2]];
degree2 = dereceler[[1]];
knot = vektörler[[2]];
knots = vektörler[[1]];
nodenum = (umax + 1)*(vmax + 1);
elnum = umax*vmax;
Do[Subscript[Subscript[w, i], j] = 1, {i, 0, umax}, {j, 0, vmax}]
Do[Subscript[N, i, 4] = 
  PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[{degree1, knot}, i, u], 
   0 <= u <= 1], {i, 0, umax}]
Do[Subscript[K, i, 4] = 
  PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[{degree2, knots}, i, v], 
   0 <= v <= 1], {i, 0, vmax}]
Subscript[S, uv] = (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(vmax\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(umax\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(i, 4\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(j, 4\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j\)], \(i\)] \(V[i]\)[j]\)\))/(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(vmax\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(umax\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(i, 4\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(j, 4\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j\)], \(i\)]\)\));
thick = Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], b]/(layer - 1);
Subscript[S, u] =D[Subscript[S, uv], u];
Subscript[S, v] = D[Subscript[S, uv], v];
unit = Norm[Cross[Subscript[S, u], Subscript[S, v]]];
ncalc = ((Cross[Subscript[S, u], Subscript[S, v]]/unit));
```

Utilizing `ReplaceAll` I am trying to solve `ncalc` equation

```
Do[u[i] = i/umax, {i, 0, umax}]
Do[v[i] = (i - 1)/vmax, {i, 0, vmax + 1}]
SetSharedFunction[n];
ParallelDo[
     n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j] = (ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}), {j, 
      1, (vmax + 1)}, {i, 0, umax}]
```

`umax` and `vmax` describe the points that end of the surface. if i want to describe the surface with alot more points `umax` and `vmax` increase...the amount of `ncalc` data and `n`  change with `umax` and `vmax` if `umax=16` `vmax=72` ;

```
SetSharedFunction[n];
ParallelDo[
         n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j] = (ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}), {j, 
          1, (vmax + 1)}, {i, 0, umax}]//AbsoluteTiming
{28321.709909, Null}
```

Is there a way to decrease the analysis time or make `ReplaceAll` faster?

---

Thanks for the help! But when I use your code I get the same timings. It is faster when it is used for `umax=9` and `vmax=2`, but when it is used for `umax=36` and `vmax=8` I get the same results.

```
SetSharedFunction[n];
ParallelDo[
     n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j] = (ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}), {j, 1, (vmax + 1)}, 
     {i, 0, umax}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1426.004146, Null}
> ```

```
(defs = ParallelTable[
     RuleDelayed[HoldPattern@Evaluate[n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j]], 
     Evaluate[ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}]], {j, 1, (vmax + 1)},
     {i, 0, umax}]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1393.181685, Null}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Related?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83891/why-is-block-significantly-faster-than-replaceall-for-inputting-variable-val -- Why do you think the slowness is due to `ReplaceAll`?  It could be the large amount of data being shuttled between the kernels....

Comment: Just how is `ncalc` defined?  It looks appropriate for `Piecewise` or `Which`, but it is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 6):

The OP's (current) definition of `ncalc` is unreadable and unsalvageable, so I made one up from pieces of the code.

```
ncalc = Piecewise[{
   {-21. + 294. u - 1029. u^2, u < 1/7},
   {2. v (131.25 - 367.5 u + 257.25 u^2), 5/7 < u < 6/7},
   {5.25, u == 6/7},
   {33.8811 v^2 , u > 1/7}},
  -1380.75 + 3160.5 u - 1800.75 u^2]
```

When you set shared variables or functions, you committing *Mathematica* to updating all kernels whenever one of them is changed.  The symbol `n` is changed at each step in your loop, which is then communicated to all the other kernels.  If you have eight kernels, you're doing eight times the work, plus the extra time spent communicating.

Functions are defined in terms of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html), which are rules of the form `HoldPattern[pattern] :> value`, where `pattern` is the pattern of the function call.  It would be much better to create these replacement rules and then to define the function via `DownValues`.

```
Clear[u, v, n];
umax = 16; vmax = 72;
Do[u[i] = i/umax, {i, 0, umax}]
Do[v[i] = (i - 1)/vmax, {i, 0, vmax + 1}]
UnsetShared[n];
(defs = ParallelTable[RuleDelayed[
      HoldPattern@Evaluate[n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j]],
      Evaluate[ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}]
      ], {j, 1, (vmax + 1)}, {i, 0, umax}]) // AbsoluteTiming // Short[#, 4] &
(*
  {0.044945 {{HoldPattern[n[1]]:>-21., HoldPattern[n[74]]:>-6.64453,
   HoldPattern[n[147]]:>-0.328125, <<12>>, HoldPattern[n[1096]]:>0.,
   HoldPattern[n[1169]]:>0.}, {<<1>>}, <<70>>, {<<1>>}}}
*)

DownValues[n] = defs;
?n
(* lots of definitions shown:
     n[1] = -21.
     ...
*)
```

Comparison with OP's:

```
Clear[u, v, n];
umax = 16; vmax = 72;
Do[u[i] = i/umax, {i, 0, umax}]
Do[v[i] = (i - 1)/vmax, {i, 0, vmax + 1}]
SetSharedFunction[n];
ParallelDo[
  n[((vmax + 1)*i) + j] := (ncalc /. {u -> u[i], v -> v[j]}), {j, 
   1, (vmax + 1)}, {i, 0, umax}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.36921, Null}  *)
```

If we make `u` and `v` five times bigger (each), the difference in timing becomes `0.46` sec. vs. `54.` sec.

Caveat: The OP defines `n` in terms of `Integer` arguments.  That means it is undefined for `Real` arguments.  So `n[1.]` will return unevaluated.  I suppose that is what is desired, but it is sometimes overlooked.

Comment: Question is edited...

Comment: @user29637 Does my answer address the underlying problem?  The actual `ncalc` does not seem to be an important part of the problem.  Rather, it's the parallelization and the use of `SetSharedFunction`.